Why does Xcode keep compiling old / cached code?
I have an iOS App that I'm also building for macOS through the "Designed for iPad" method. So, no Catalyst. It stopped build my updated code and it keeps building a kind of cached code. Example: I have a NSLog that printed "HOME" and now I changed it in "HOME NEW".
The app still prints the old code "HOME".
I did all that I could think. Clearing derived data, build folder... nothings seems to work. Even deleting the whole repo and redownloading it didn't work, so I think it's something related to the bundle ID of the App. Any ideas?
I'm on macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 and Xcode 15.4

Have you cleaned the trash, after removing derived data ?, after opening xcode, check its target in show in finder, and also search HOME in your project.

Yeah, nothing helped.

If it is a device try to restart the app, and it is simulator try to reset

As I specified in the question is neither a physical external device or a simulator. It's a "native" macOS App.

What's the Designed for iPad method?  Can you elaborate?

There is mainly two way to deliver a macOS App: Catalyst (rewriting a lot of it) or reusing the same code of the iOS / iPad one. The latter is called "Designed for iPad".

Bro, If I were you I'll use symbolic break point to catch the LOC who prints old "HOME": Here are the steps:

Open the Breakpoint Navigator in Xcode (the second tab in the left panel).
Click on the '+' button at the bottom left of the navigator and select "Symbolic Breakpoint...".
3.In the dialog that appears, enter NSLog in the "Symbol" field.
Click "Done" and run your app.


Hi! Thanks for the answer but that doesn't help because I can't put any valid breakpoints in the code. They appear "dotted". By the way, no offense, but I'm a developer since 16 years, so it's not something that simple. There is clearly some kind of bug that doesn't let me clean the cache of my App and it happened 99% after updating to macOS Sonoma.

Yeah, agreed, but last thing to confirm: can we use hopper or just binary editors like HexFriend to search for the "HOME" or "HOME NEW" in the built products, they should appear in the Strings section of the built binary. And that maybe the must straight forward way to validate if Xcode caches the old code, right?

That was just an example. I can (and I did) write a lot of new bunch lines of codes and it ignores it. I removed like 80% of a class and it does still compiles it and act like nothing changed.

We can help you better if you provide a minimal example to reproduce this issue. If that is convenient to you

I really don't know how to reproduce it. It's something not code related, but it's something more related to a kind of cache of my code that got bugged.

Have you tried to build via command line, instead of using xcode ?

While debugging, you might be using the "Simulate" option. Try building an archive (Product -> Archive) and then running the app from the archive. This can sometimes bypass certain development-related caching mechanisms.
